# LibCurl dependencies missing from PHP 7.2.7 Installation

Tags: php, php-curl, uwamp

Downloading the binaries from [PHP.Net](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) I don't see any **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll**, but in the install.txt it says it is bundled:

> php_curl.dll CURL, Client URL library functions Requires: libeay32.dll,
> ssleay32.dll (bundled)

I have no problems with enabling cURL on my older PHP installation as these files are in there. I'm currently using [UWAMP](https://www.uwamp.com), but it seems the PHP.NET v7.2.7 packages doesn't have these DLLs as well.

Comment: I have run into the same situation.  After installing PHP 7.2.7, cURL is not bundled.